# How to update local storage value in react Native?

Tags: react-native, local-storage

I am trying to update the local storage value in react native app.
I can set and read the value but can't update it.
I hope this community can help me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use LocalStorage in React-Native, you can use [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) instead.

You can also use a store like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to handle this.